# NSMutableArray Resetting Itself?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I am having an issue with NSMutableArray wiping its contents.

Consider my code: (int i; is in my file's .h as is NSMutableArray* newFileControllerArray)

```
-(void)awakeFromNib{
    i = 0;
    newFileWindowControllerArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}

-(IBAction)newFileMenubar:(id)sender{    
    [newFileWindowControllerArray addObject:[[NewFileWindowController alloc]initWithWindowNibName:@"NewFileWindowController"]];
    NSUInteger elementsInArray = [newFileWindowControllerArray count];
    NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)elementsInArray);
    [[newFileWindowControllerArray objectAtIndex:i] showWindow:nil];
}

-(IBAction)OKButtonClicked:(id)sender{
    NSUInteger elementsInArray = [newFileWindowControllerArray count];
    NSLog(@"THERE ARE %lu ELEMENTS IN THE ARRAY",(unsigned long)elementsInArray);
}
```

The first method called (other than `awakeFromNib:`) is `newFileMenubar:` This will add one element to the array. I can confirm that this works because 1 is printed in the console. However, once `OKbutton` is called and I print out the number of elements in my array it says that no elements are in the array. Why is that?

Am I missing something very obvious here? Why does my array reset itself?

**EDIT:** 
The comments have gotten long and unwieldy so here is the code w/NSLogs and outputs:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib{
    i = 0;
   newFileWindowControllerArray = [NSMutableArray array];


      NSLog(@"self=%p, array=%p", self, newFileWindowControllerArray);
   }

 -(IBAction)newFileMenubar:(id)sender{

     [newFileWindowControllerArray addObject:[[NewFileWindowController           alloc]initWithWindowNibName:@"NewFileWindowController"]];


[[newFileWindowControllerArray objectAtIndex:i] showWindow:nil];


i++;

    NSLog(@"self=%p, array=%p", self, newFileWindowControllerArray);

 }

-(IBAction)OKButtonClicked:(id)sender{
NSUInteger elementsInArray = [newFileWindowControllerArray count];


NSLog(@"self=%p, array=%p", self, newFileWindowControllerArray);


[documentController newDocument:sender];
[[newFileWindowControllerArray objectAtIndex:i]close];


 }
```

When the program launches, this is the output: self=0x100141480, array=0x100140f30
This should be coming from awakeFromNib:

The next method called is newFileMenubar:

The output from this is

self=0x1001ac990, array=0x1005228a0 and immediately after self=0x100141480, array=0x100140f30

The last method called is OKButtonClicked:

The output from the last method (OKButtonClicked:) is self=0x1001ac990, array=0x1005228a0

As you can see from the code, the name of the array doesn't change, but my outputs beg to differ? What could cause this?

Comment: print the array itself, too (%@), make sure it isn't null

Comment: could we we see the declaration of the array?  likely cause is that it's declared in such a way that it's not retained

Comment: The array is declared like so:  NSMutableArray *newFileWindowControllerArray; in my interface. I am using ARC

Comment: Are you sure that it is the *same instance* of your object in newFileMenubar and newFileMenubar? Is the newFileWindowControllerArray still the same object? Perhaps also add an NSLog in awakeFromNib.

Comment: I believe that the arrays are the same instance. When I add a log to print the array itself it has a value of ( ) in awakeFromNib: In newFileMenubar the array has a hexadecimal value. Under OKButton: it reverts back to ( )

Comment: @Blakeasd: Perhaps add `NSLog(@"self=%p, array=%p", self, newFileWindowControllerArray)` in all three methods and show the result.

Comment: Is that the code of your app delegate class?

Comment: You talk about `myNewFileControllerArray` in your .h and you use `newFileWindowControllerArray` in your .m, are you sure to use the same object ?

Comment: I made a typo when I say myNewFileControllerArray here on StackOverflow, it's just newFileWindowControllerArray. In awakeFromNib: I get: self=0x101004780, array=0x101004cb0 In newFileMenubar I get: self=0x10108b910, array=0x1001cd240 and also self=0x101004780, array=0x101004cb0 In OKbuttonClicked: I get self=0x10108b910, array=0x1001cd240
Hopefully this wil provide some more clues! Thanks Everyone!

Comment: No, this is not in my App-Delegate Class as my project is Document based

Comment: @Blakeasd: It is easier to read if you add the output to your question, preferably in chronological order, together with the output of the array counts. - Note that there are *two* instances of your objects.

Comment: @Martin R: I've edited my question to reflect where the NSLogs are and their respective outputs.

Answer (score 1):

There are good clues in your log output.  There are multiple instances of the view controller (see the different values for 'self'?).  They each have their own array.  See this code...

```
-(IBAction)newFileMenubar:(id)sender{    
    [newFileWindowControllerArray addObject:[[NewFileWindowController alloc]initWithWindowNibName:@"NewFileWindowController"]];
```

When you press the button associated with that action, your app builds another view controller and places it in the array.  That view controller gets the awake from nib message and allocates *another* array, and so on.

To confirm this, change the code as follows:

```
-(IBAction)newFileMenubar:(id)sender{    
    [newFileWindowControllerArray addObject:@"Hello world"];

    // and comment this out, for now:
    // [[newFileWindowControllerArray objectAtIndex:i] showWindow:nil];
```

In the other methods, comment out your expectations that the array has anything other than strings in it, and see what you get.  e.g. ...

```
- (IBAction)OKButtonClicked:(id)sender {

    NSUInteger elementsInArray = [newFileWindowControllerArray count];
    NSLog(@"self=%p, array=%p", self, newFileWindowControllerArray);
    [documentController newDocument:sender];

    // and comment this out, for now:
    // [[newFileWindowControllerArray objectAtIndex:i]close];

    // instead...
    NSLog(@"danh thinks my array will be ok: %@", newFileWindowControllerArray);
}
```

You probably do not mean to create another view controller on every button press, but I'm not sure what function you do want.  Maybe you want an array of views?  (To create many view controllers under the control of another, you'll want to read up on [container view controllers, here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW6)).

Comment: Thanks! I got an address when I commented out my lines and added your NSLog. This code is all in a class labeled 'NewFileHandler' that is a subclass of NSObject. Does that still mean that awakeFromNib: gets called again once newFileMenubar: is finished being run? If so, where should I put the code that's in awakeFromNib: to get everything setup. I basically just need an array to store those NSWindowControllers so I can reference them to open up new windows in newFileMenubar: and OKButton: . I'm lost on where I should put my new methods. Any help is appreciated, and thanks again!

Comment: The awake from nib is okay (you can use that, though initWithCoder is a more common choice).  The problem is the idea that this vc allocates new instances of itself and holds them in an array.  If you really are creating a container view controller, see the link I posted, and for example the method addChildViewController: on UIViewController.

Comment: Your view controller already has a view, and the more common thing to do is create subviews of the at view (instances of UIView that you add by saying [self.view addSubview:someNewView]).  You could do that all up front (in the nib even) and hide them all.  When user presses buttons you un-hide them.

Comment: I'm not using any view controllers, as my project is for OS X and not iOS. Instead I'm populating my array with NSWindowControllers. What I am attempting to do is store the NSWindowControllers in an NSMutableArray so I can 'dynamically' create new instances upon an IBAction. Then I take the NSWindowControllers at a specific index and show the window using a method on that index in the array. I wonder why I get an address with your code... Any idea on how I can get this darn thing going? I sincerely appreciate all the advice you've given me!

Comment: Oh gosh, I should have looked more closely at the post's tags.  I'm a kind of a fish out of water in osx.  My uneducated opinion is that this needs to take place outside of NewFileWindowController or any of it's subclasses.  That some other object that isn't a NewFileWindowController should be in charge of allocating them and adding them to the array.  Having the class you posted allocate itself generates the recursion that got you into trouble in the first place.  In iOS we'd say you're creating a view controller container which is a very different class than the view controllers it contains.